# Parameters for Audio File Streaming in Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, bigdata

I am trying to stream audio files that are added to my HDFS every few minutes. There is a great deal of documentation on using FileStream for text files in Spark but there is none for audio files (like .wav format). The parameters for streaming text files from HDFS are following:

```
val linesRDD = ssc.fileStream (LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat) (hdfs:cnesi:8085/data/test)
```

where `LongWritable = key , Text = Value , TextInputFormat = File Format`

I wanted to ask what will be equivalent for these three parameters for .wav audio files and which libraries or packages do I need to stream this data.

I am using spark 1.6.1.

Any help and guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and think about writing a question that will help other (and you) in the future.

Comment: Hi Zhon, to be more specific, I am trying to read files whenever a new file gets stored in HDFS using Spark streaming API. Can you provide any help or example code for the same ? Look forward to your reply.

Comment: I am not trying to answer your question, I am trying to get you to improve your question. As your question stands, it is unclear, too broad, and doesn't show your effort.